# Regex for excluding a pattern of more than 2 "==" in Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract any text between one or more than 2 equals to(i.e. ==,===,===,==== etc) and subsequent text until it searches for next one or more than 2 equals and store in array list.

Ex:

```
==Notes and references== {{Refli=st|35e=m}}=====Bibliography=====Text starts
```

Expected output:

```
[==Notes and references== {{Refli=st|35e=m}}, =====Bibliography=====Text starts]
```

I have got the regex syntax:

```
"==+([^==+]*)==+([^==+]*)";
```

Output i am getting until it encounters single =:

```
[==Notes and references== {{Refli, =====Bibliography=====Text starts]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[^==+]*` matches all characters except `=` and `+`. This is not what you want.

Here, it might be easier to use something like:

```
"==+(.*?)==+(.*?)(?===|$)";
```

So that you can allow single `=` signs in between the multiple `=`.

`(?===|$)` is a positive lookahead (`(?= ... )`) and makes sure there's either two consecutive `=` signs ahead or there's the end of the string.

---

Or if you want to negate specifically the `==+` in the parts in between you can use negative lookaheads:

```
"==+((?:(?!==+).)*)==+((?:(?!==+).)*)";
```

This syntax `((?:(?!==+).)*)` will check for every character and make sure it isn't a `==` (or more).

Comment: Thank you Jerry. I got it working as I wanted. Can you pleas explain how (?===|$) in "==+(.*?)==+(.*?)(?===|$)"  searches text until next multiple =.

Comment: Also, I am looking forward to use one more regex to get the text part " {{Refli=st|35e=m}}" from "==Notes and references== {{Refli=st|35e=m}}".

Comment: @user2778173 Doesn't the regex already give you this? See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/uD6kL6). I added an explanation for the positive lookahead `(?= ... )`

Comment: No, the regex captures ==XXX==xxxx from ==XXX==xxxx===YYY===yyyy part (original text), Now I need to get only xxxx from the matched string (i.e. ==XXX==xxxx)

Comment: @user2778173 You should be able to get xxxx from group(2). Could you indicate how you're accessing the groups?

Comment: I could not understand your question. What do you mean by group 2? Could you please explain?

Comment: @Vin See this [ideone demo](http://ideone.com/ZZA2cl) and note how I called the variables you're looking for.

Comment: @Vin Huh? What's wrong with it? I'm getting all the groups you've mentioned. See [ideone demo](http://ideone.com/1pRmFM).

Comment: the below code is the implementation of the logic, I am not able to store the match.group(2) string. It's not getting stored,

Comment: @Vin Could you fork an ideone and put the link here? It's hard to read it on a one liner ^^

Comment: @Vin I'm not sure what's wrong. It seems to be [working](http://ideone.com/hzPe5v) for me. Does `System.out.println("XXXXXXXXX"+text);` output something?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2pyEYCkJ This is the input String i am taking as input for the syntax you have given. the code doesn't capture the matcher.group(2).

Comment: @Vin There are multiple groups there; the first title being career. Ans since your input spans over several lines, you will have to use the s modifier like this: `"(?s)==+((?:(?!==+).)*)==+((?:(?!==+).)*)";`